# Expression logical statements using rules of inference with quantifiers

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

So in my Discrete Mathematics class, the professor went well over the topics of both Propositional & Predicate logic as well as Rules of Inference but he did not explain how to express logical, propositional statements using rules of inference with quantifiers.

I have the following sets:

A = {Discrete Math Students}

B = {Boolean Algebra Students}

C = {All Students}

I am asked to formalise the following statement:

*P: If someone is a student of Discrete Mathematics, then, they must study Boolean Algebra.*

With propositional logic, this would be something like p -> q but I'm really stuck.  How do I express these statements in the way that is asked?

Comment: If x $\in A$ then $x\in B$, no?

Comment: @topologicalmagician I think it involves notation like ∀ and ∃ but not sure.

Comment: $\forall x (x\in A \implies x\in B)$, no?

Comment: @topologicalmagician I guess.  It looks about right but I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 1):

> If someone is a student of Discrete Mathematics, then, they must study Boolean Algebra.

The "someone" is a *bit* of a miscue, since "they *must*" actually indicates that this is *in fact* a universal statement.

Thus you need to express: "**For any one, if they are in the set of Disctrete Mathematics Students, then they are in the set of Boolean Algebra Students**," using a universal quantifier ($\forall$), a term (such as $x$), the inclusion operator ($\in$), the conditional operator ($\to$), and whichever of the sets ($A,B,C$) are appropriate.